# Django URLConf setting not working

Tags: regex, django

I've been looking at this now for hours and cannot seem to work out why it's not working. I'm trying to setup a regex to allow the following URL:

```
/news/monthly/2015/July/
```

Here is the URLConf setting:

```
url(r'^news/monthly/(?P<year>\d)/(?P<month>\w+)/$', 'Bolton_GC.News.views.monthlynews', name='monthlynews')
```

Can anyone spot the mistake because I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Wayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `+` quantifier with `\d` (without it, only 1 digit is matched):

```
r'^news/monthly/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\w+)/$'
                           ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK3dI4/2)

See [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) article for more details about `+` quantifier:

> The **plus** tells the engine **to attempt to match the preceding token once or more**.

Answer (score 2):

In the examples, the number is either given with `(?P<year>[0-9]{4})` or with \d+ as in :

```
url(r'^news/monthly/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\w+)/$', 'Bolton_GC.News.views.monthlynews', name='monthlynews')
```

Hope it helped!